# How can we combine two files based on a condition in awk command?

Tags: bash, shell, csv, awk, command-prompt

I have two text files which has space seperated values, i want to combine the files based on a key column from both files and output in another file.
**location.txt**

```
1 21.5 23
2 24.5 20
3 19.5 19
4 22.5 15
5 24.5 12
6 19.5 12
```

**data.txt** which has milllion of data, but i will give simple few entries here,

```
2004-03-31 03:38:15.757551 2 1 122.153 -3.91901 11.04 2.03397
2004-02-28 00:59:16.02785 3 2 19.9884 37.0933 45.08 2.69964
2004-02-28 01:03:16.33393 11 3 19.3024 38.4629 45.08 2.68742
2004-02-28 01:06:16.013453 17 4 19.1652 38.8039 45.08 2.68742
2004-02-28 01:06:46.778088 18 5 19.175 38.8379 45.08 2.69964
2004-02-28 01:08:45.992524 22 6 19.1456 38.9401 45.08 2.68742
```

What i trying is to combine these two files based on the key value of **column 1 from location.txt** and **column 4 from data.txt** and get the result in format as below by combining **all the data from data.txt** and **column 2 and 3 from location.txt**..

```
2004-03-31 03:38:15.757551 2 1 122.153 -3.91901 11.04 2.03397 21.5 23
2004-02-28 00:59:16.02785 3 2 19.9884 37.0933 45.08 2.69964 24.5 20
2004-02-28 01:03:16.33393 11 3 19.3024 38.4629 45.08 2.68742 19.5 19
2004-02-28 01:06:16.013453 17 4 19.1652 38.8039 45.08 2.68742 22.5 15
2004-02-28 01:06:46.778088 18 5 19.175 38.8379 45.08 2.69964 24.5 12
2004-02-28 01:08:45.992524 22 6 19.1456 38.9401 45.08 2.68742 19.5 12
```

I'm using awk command:

```
awk -F' ' "NR==FNR{label[$1]=$1;x[$1]=$2;y[$1]=$3;next}; ($2==label[$2]){print $0 "," x[$2] y[$3]}" location.txt data.txt > result.txt
```

But I'm not getting the output as i expected, Can anyone help me fix this?
can we get the result file in csv format with space replaced with comma?

Comment: suggestions: 1) shorten sample data to say 5 lines and reduce columns to say 5 only.. 2) show your expected output exactly as you need, it is easy to miss what you wrote at the end 3) try to explain more how the output is arrived at, not easy to infer from your code

Comment: I'm not familiar with awk, but by refering many examples i have written awk command. what I trying to do is to append the location.txt data to the data.txt file by compairing the 1st and 4th column of location.txt and data.txt file respectively, and store the  output in new file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In awk:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {                  # process location.txt
    a[$1]=$2 OFS $3        # hash using $1 as key
    next                   # next record
}
$4 in a {                  # process data.txt
    print $0,a[$4]         # output record and related location 
}' location.txt  data.txt  # mind the file order
2004-03-31 03:38:15.757551 2 1 122.153 -3.91901 11.04 2.03397 21.5 23
2004-02-28 00:59:16.02785 3 2 19.9884 37.0933 45.08 2.69964 24.5 20
2004-02-28 01:03:16.33393 11 3 19.3024 38.4629 45.08 2.68742 19.5 19
2004-02-28 01:06:16.013453 17 4 19.1652 38.8039 45.08 2.68742 22.5 15
2004-02-28 01:06:46.778088 18 5 19.175 38.8379 45.08 2.69964 24.5 12
2004-02-28 01:08:45.992524 22 6 19.1456 38.9401 45.08 2.68742 19.5 12
```

Comment: Thank you@JamesBrown, got output as i expected.

Answer (score 1):

With bash and join

```
join -1 1 -2 4 <(sort -k1,1 -n location.txt) <(sort -k4,4 -n data.txt) -o 2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5,2.6,2.7,2.8,1.2,1.3
```

Output:

```
2004-03-31 03:38:15.757551 2 1 122.153 -3.91901 11.04 2.03397 21.5 23
2004-02-28 00:59:16.02785 3 2 19.9884 37.0933 45.08 2.69964 24.5 20
2004-02-28 01:03:16.33393 11 3 19.3024 38.4629 45.08 2.68742 19.5 19
2004-02-28 01:06:16.013453 17 4 19.1652 38.8039 45.08 2.68742 22.5 15
2004-02-28 01:06:46.778088 18 5 19.175 38.8379 45.08 2.69964 24.5 12
2004-02-28 01:08:45.992524 22 6 19.1456 38.9401 45.08 2.68742 19.5 12
```

---

See: `man join`